# If $X,Y$ are equivalence relations, so is $X \times Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

> If $X,Y$ are reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, then $X \times Y$ is an equivalence relation where ${(a,b):a\in X, b\in Y}$.

I am trying to self learn these topics. I do know what an equivalence relation is. I wanted to know how would someone prove that $X\times Y$ be an equivalence relation?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: What do you mean by $X\times Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are relations? Is $X$ a relationship on $A$ and $Y$ a relationship on $B$ and $X\times Y$ a relationship on $A\times B$? And what does this have to do with the Cantor set in the title?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I edited this question

Comment: Prove definition?

Comment: One does not prove definitions. The original version of this question actually made sense (apart from the irrelevant mention of Cantor sets); this version does not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I will change it back because that is what I wanted.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I editted back to the original version. Cantor sets was irrelevant. Sorry about that. Can you help me with the origianl question

Comment: I'm still confused by this question. @BrianM.Scott can you really make sense of that first line?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It look like both Thomas and I need your help.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, on the assumption that the author of the theorem was very sloppily identifying $(A\times B)\times(A\times B)$ with $(A\times A)\times(B\times B)$ in the obvious way. It’s appallingly sloppy, but I’ve seen things that bad before, and I’m writing an answer using and explaining that assumption.

Comment: Yeah, but the other sloppiness is that, if that was what the q meant, why wouldn't they just say that $X,Y$ are equivalence relations? Your interpreation was my first guess, but it's not a particularly good way of phrasing it, particular leaving the sets that $X,Y$ are relations on completely out of the question. Heck, even using $X,Y$ for relationships seems sloppy, when $R,S,\dots$ are usual. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Thomas: You’ll get no argument from me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that $X$ is an equivalence relation on some set $A$, and $Y$ is an equivalence relation on some set $B$. It appears, then, that we’re being asked to prove that $X\times Y$ is an equivalence relation on $A\times B$.

Technically this isn’t actually true: a relation on $A\times B$ is a subset of $(A\times B)\times(A\times B)$, while $X\times Y$ is a subset of $(A\times A)\times(B\times B)$, and

$$(A\times B)\times(A\times B)\tag{1}$$

and

$$(A\times A)\times(B\times B)\tag{2}$$

are not the same set. Elements of $(1)$ have the form $\big\langle\langle a_1,b_1\rangle,\langle a_2,b_2\rangle\big\rangle$, where $a_1,a_2\in A$ and $b_1,b_2\in B$, while elements of $(2)$ have the form $\big\langle\langle a_1,a_2\rangle,\langle b_1,b_2\rangle\big\rangle$, where again $a_1,a_2\in A$ and $b_1,b_2\in B$. However, there is a natural correspondence between the sets $(1)$ and $(2)$, the one that matches the element

$$\big\langle\langle a_1,b_1\rangle,\langle a_2,b_2\rangle\big\rangle\in(A\times B)\times(A\times B)$$

with the element

$$\big\langle\langle a_1,a_2\rangle,\langle b_1,b_2\rangle\big\rangle\in(A\times A)\times(B\times B)\;;$$

if this theorem is taken from a book or set of notes, I imagine that the author is silently (and sloppily) expecting us to use this correspondence to treat $(1)$ and $(2)$ as if they were the same set. (If that’s not the case, then the question simply does not make sense at all.) I will use the equivalence explicitly.

To be precise, let

$$R=\left\{\big\langle\langle a_1,b_1\rangle,\langle a_2,b_2\rangle\big\rangle:\big\langle\langle a_1,a_2\rangle,\langle b_1,b_2\rangle\big\rangle\in X\times Y\right\}\;;\tag{3}$$

we want to show that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A\times B$, i.e., that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

> **Reflexivity:** We must show that for each $\langle a,b\rangle\in A\times B$, $\big\langle\langle a,b\rangle,\langle a,b\rangle\big\rangle\in R$.

Let $\langle a,b\rangle\in A\times B$. Then $a\in A$, and $X$ is reflexive, so $\langle a,a\rangle\in X$. Similarly, $b\in B$, and $Y$ is reflexive, so $\langle b,b\rangle\in Y$. But then $\big\langle\langle a,\color{brown}a\rangle,\langle\color{green}b,\color{purple}b\rangle\big\rangle\in X\times Y$, and therefore

$$\big\langle\langle a,\color{green}b\rangle,\langle\color{brown}a,\color{purple}b\rangle\big\rangle\in R$$

by $(3)$.

> **Symmetry:** Suppose that $\big\langle\langle a_1,b_1\rangle,\langle a_2,b_2\rangle\big\rangle\in R$: we need to show that $\big\langle\langle a_2,b_2\rangle,\langle a_1,b_1\rangle\big\rangle\in R$ as well.

Since $\big\langle\langle a_1,b_1\rangle,\langle a_2,b_2\rangle\big\rangle\in R$, $(3)$ tells us that $\big\langle\langle a_1,a_2\rangle,\langle b_1,b_2\rangle\big\rangle\in X\times Y$ and hence that $\langle a_1,a_2\rangle\in X$ and $\langle b_1,b_2\rangle\in Y$. But $X$ and $Y$, being equivalence relations, are symmetric by hypothesis, so $\langle a_2,a_1\rangle\in X$ and $\langle b_2,b_1\rangle\in Y$. Thus, $\big\langle\langle a_2,a_1\rangle,\langle b_2,b_1\rangle\big\rangle\in X\times Y$, and by applying $(3)$ again we see that

$$\big\langle\langle a_2,b_2\rangle,\langle a_1,b_1\rangle\big\rangle\in R\;,$$

as desired.

> **Transitivity:** Suppose that $\big\langle\langle a_1,b_1\rangle,\langle a_2,b_2\rangle\big\rangle\in R$ and $\big\langle\langle a_2,b_2\rangle,\langle a_3,b_3\rangle\big\rangle\in R$; we want to show that $\big\langle\langle a_1,b_1\rangle,\langle a_3,b_3\rangle\big\rangle\in R$.

As before, we know from $(3)$ that $\langle a_1,a_2\rangle\in X$ and $\langle b_1,b_2\rangle\in Y$. Similarly, applying $(3)$ to the hypothesis that $\big\langle\langle a_2,b_2\rangle,\langle a_3,b_3\rangle\big\rangle\in R$, we find that $\langle a_2,a_3\rangle\in X$ and $\langle b_2,b_3\rangle\in Y$. Being an equivalence relation, $X$ is transitive, and we have $\langle a_1,a_2\rangle\in X$ and $\langle a_2,a_3\rangle\in X$, so $\langle a_1,a_3\rangle\in X$. $Y$ is also transitive, so a completely similar argument shows that $\langle b_1,b_3\rangle\in Y$. Thus, $\big\langle\langle a_1,a_3\rangle,\langle a_3,b_3\rangle\big\rangle\in X\times Y$, and $(3)$ tells us that

$$\big\langle\langle a_1,b_1\rangle,\langle a_3,b_3\rangle\big\rangle\in R\;,$$

just as we wanted.

Since $R$ is a reflexive, symmetric, and transitive relation on $A\times B$, it is by definition an equivalence relation on $A\times B$. And as we saw above, there is a natural equivalence — technically, a bijection — between $R$ and $X\times Y$; if we (sloppily) pretend that the equivalence is actually an identity, we can say that $X\times Y$ is an equivalence relation on $A\times B$. (I myself would not do so, **especially** in an introductory course: that kind of sloppiness is more confusing than helpful until one really understands the basics of set theory.)

Comment: Yes! This is what I was trying to prove for a while now. Thank you Brian! It's just when I was reading this book with a friend I was just trying to make sense of this while teaching myself. I understood it your way. This really helps. Thank you for explaining with detail. Thank You again!

Comment: @carlon: You’re very welcome!

Comment: this is a great answer